# trying to get symfony/dotenv to work in my codeigniter app

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am trying to get symfony/dotenv working in my codeigniter app. (in a docker container fyi..)

Help from other articles i have done::

In my codeigniter app i have

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.7",
    "symfony/dotenv": "^5.4"
},
```

in the vendor directory i see it installed

I have modified my php.ini

```
RUN sed -E -i -e 's/variables_order = "GPCS"/variables_order = "EGPCS"/' /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

in application/config/config.php I have changed to the following:

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = FCPATH .'vendor/autoload.php';
```

but when i go to the app i am getting the error

```
Message: Class "Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv" not found

Filename: /var/www/html/application/config/hooks.php

Line Number: 23
```

I must be missing something. Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do a

```
composer update
```

after

```
composer install --prefer-dist --no-scripts --no-interaction --no-autoloader --no-dev
```

That resolve my issue